# Detect if key value is refer by foreign key

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model (Model1) that can be refer (by foreign key) by other models (In my example below only by Model2, but we can have Model3, 4, ...).

```
public class Model1 
{
    [key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ....
}

public class Model2
{
    [key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    
    [ForeignKey("Model1")]
    public Guid? model1Id {get; set;}
    public Model1 Model1 {get;set;}
}
```

I don't want to declare a virtual properties on Model1 for each other models that refer this model.

How can I detect if the Model1.Id is refer by a 'remote' foreign key to avoid constraint violation on delete of Model1 ?

Thanks in advance,
Yannick

Comment: That would be a perfect reason to do add collection properties (not per se virtual) that you can check with a cheap `!model1.Models2.Any()` in a Where. What's the reason for not wanting that?

Comment: because Model1 is declared in an assembly to be resused in other project where model2 don't exist.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you have to do it the hard way, i.e. by knowing (or finding) the referring tables.